# Max() function not returns the max value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, max

I used `MAX()` to retrive max value from column. But it returns wrong output.
Here what the `Max()` returns . Kindly Suggest

```
SELECT Seq_No FROM Appltype WHERE App_No = '01'
```

Output is : `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

```
SELECT MAX(Seq_No) FROM Appltype WHERE App_No = '01'
```

Output is : `9` 
Can't able to attach image as I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: The output is correct, the values are not numeric and 9 is alphabetical greater than 10. If you want the max numeric, you have to cast.

Comment: @Vicky- If MegaTron's reply is what you are looking for. Please accept it as answer

Comment: I can't understand why people always think the problem is with Microsoft and not with the code they write or the data they use. 99.9% of the cases the problem is misunderstanding the proper use of the system function, and not the system functions themselves.

Comment: @ZoharPeled This problem crops up again and again in different systems - not just Microsoft's. Because the data is ostensibly numeric and the datatype isn't (usually) displayed, people naturally think it is a systems problem.

Comment: @RobbieDee of course it's not only in Microsoft...

Comment: * Posts handbag emoji * ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The field `Seq_No` is not numeric type. Please try this query:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(Seq_No as INT)) 
FROM   Appltype 
WHERE  App_No = '01'
```